# Software for "live" FFT with movable sliders

Tags: gui, signal-processing

I am looking for a software that displays the FFT of a signal and provides a GUI which allows me to conveniently move or resize the window to select only a part of my signal while updating the FFT "live".

I have many different signals to analyse (generated by my own software and saved in text files with two columns) and the frequencies present in my signal vary from time to time. So it would be very helpful to focus on particular parts of my signal, in particular a convenient way to select only a certain part of my signal would be incredibly helpful.

I have googled quite a bit but cannot find a software that does this "window change" live.

If that software provided a Prony analysis as well, that would be another useful thing.

---

I should add that the software should run on Linux or Mac and hopefully be free.

I just found ScopeDSP which perhaps could provide what I want (?) but at $299 that is not affordable for me and also it runs only on Windows.

Comment: If you say which OS this is to run on you may get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

While designed for other applications (RF), [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/) does what you are asking (and is free open source software!).  You may have to write your own adapter for your specific hardware andCSV format, but there is a huge userbase. It easily performs real-time time and frequency domain analysis as well as providing a plethora of signal processing tools.

Comment: I don't have it set up at the moment to take a screenshot.  It is something that I have used in the past  that does what the OP requests.  And as you mentioned it is FOSS!

Comment: I have spend some time getting GNU Radio to work and I can see that it somehow would be able to do what I want -- I just couldn't get my head around it. Instead, I have now written my own script that works together with gnuplot and does what I want: I bound the "f" key to piping the current gnuplot state into a python script which calculates the FFT of my currently zoomed in data; then, another gnuplot window constantly displays the data that are produced by the python script, giving a "sort-of-live" feeling (max. 1 second delay).